# Difference between flex display property and block display property

Tags: html, css

What is the difference between flex and block display property?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        .flex{
            display: flex;
            background-color: red;
            height: 200px;
        }
        .block{
            height: 200px;
            background-color: rgb(51, 170, 120);
            display: block;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit <p class="flex">Hello</p> adipisicing elit. Alias velit optio, quod tenetur omnis, in voluptas corporis voluptatem quaerat iure reprehenderit quasi accusamus sed dignissimos odio ex ipsam dolor consequatur.</div>

    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit <p class="block">Hello</p> adipisicing elit. Alias velit optio, quod tenetur omnis, in voluptas corporis voluptatem quaerat iure reprehenderit quasi accusamus sed dignissimos odio ex ipsam dolor consequatur.</div>
</body>
</html>
```

In this code both are working same. Can anyone help me please?? :(

Comment: You can read about flexbox here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox

Comment: Had you put the classes on the `div` elements instead of the `p` elements you'd have seen a substantial difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first glance they look similar, but they are not...
The key is that `display: flex` has access to the **`flexbox model`** feature. To check this in action, you can add to `.flex` class selector two properties: `align-items: center;` and `justify-content: center;`

- `display block` "The element generates a block element box, generating line breaks both before and after the element when in the normal flow." [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display)
- `display flex` "The element behaves like a block element and lays out its content according to the **[flexbox model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout)**." [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display)